# How do I resample data, aggregating values, in Pandas dataframe with a continuous-time numeric index to discrete integer time?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe where the index is a float representing continuous time (e.g, in seconds).
and I have a values column with 0s and 1s indicating when an event happened. I want to obtain the number of events in every whole second interval. If the index was DateTime format, I could use `df.resample` with `sum` as the aggregation function.

How can I do this with a floating point index?

example code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': np.random.randint(0,2,25)}, index = np.arange(0,5,0.2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': np.random.randint(0,2,25)}, index = np.arange(0,5,0.2))
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s', errors='coerce')
df = df.resample('1s').agg({'value': 'sum'})
df.index = df.index.time
print(df)

          value
00:00:00      3
00:00:01      2
00:00:02      0
00:00:03      2
00:00:04      3
```

Comment: Nice Solution. The other one I found involved using np.histogram. This is more elegant.

Comment: by the way, you don't need to filter. you can simply do df.resample('1s').sum()